# Dockerizing the an application, throws 'npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory' while running npm install

Tags: node.js, docker

I created a docker file for my application. This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.20.1-alpine3.15
RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
USER app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

When trying to build an image using
`docker build -t app .`  It is failing at npm install instruction, with the following error

```
#9 30.84 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata-e29272c3/estoniaLow.d.ts'
#9 30.86 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/tslint-78b3aa2e/lib/rules/completed-docs/exclusion.d.ts'
#9 30.86 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/rxjs-c65985b6/_esm2015/internal/OuterSubscriber.js'
#9 30.87 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/rxjs-31d24ad4/operators/onErrorResumeNext.js'
#9 30.87 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@angular/compiler-cli-923906dd/ngcc/src/ngcc_options.js'
```

I even tried to clear the cache and made sure the user had enough privileges.

Comment: Shot in the dark here, but when I copy files I set the user to that of the `USER` e.g. `COPY --chown=app package*.json ./` I also stick the the "node" user and use the home directory so `WORKDIR /home/node`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I faced the same issue. Just to debug, I tried copying the **package.json** file only instead of package*.json, rebuild the image then the following error popped up.

```
#9 78.90 npm ERR! code ENOENT
#9 78.90 npm ERR! syscall spawn git
#9 78.90 npm ERR! path git
#9 78.91 npm ERR! errno -2
#9 78.93 npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
#9 78.93 npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/zingchart/zingchart-constants.git
#9 78.93 npm ERR! enoent
#9 78.94 npm ERR! enoent
#9 78.94 npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
#9 78.94 npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
#9 78.94 npm ERR! enoent
```

As git, bash are not part of alpine. So installing git & bash would solve the problem. So add the below command before npm install instruction

`RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add --no-cache bash git openssh`

or simply use `apk add --no-cache bash git openssh`

If you are using some user to install, have appropriate permission (like root) else it throws **unable to lock the package database**.

Dockerfile would look this

```
FROM node:14.20.1-alpine3.15
RUN apk add --no-cache bash git openssh
RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
USER app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: What `package.json` file did you use for this? I didn't see one in the question, if you're using your own then perhaps you have some dependencies that require bash, git, and openssh to be installed - but I didn't see from your answer how this was relevant to the OP's question?

Comment: @a2k42 In the question error logs, it is mentioned Error NO ENTry for GIT (ENOENT). So GIT is missing in his setup as a result node modules file is missing. As I'm not aware of app USER permissions suggested to install packages in ROOT user.